# Change datetime custom format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have created a column of `datetime` type in SQL Server.

The output of this column is:

```
1994-01-10
```

But I want to show only year, like this: `1994` (not long datetime)

How can I change this format type of `datetime`?

My table is `tbl_borrowing`, my column is `VitiBotimit`

Thank you

Comment: you could just change the column to an int type

Comment: `select year(VitiBotimit) from tbl_borrowing`.  [Please try google.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20year%20part%20of%20date)

Comment: You sent me query that show only year in my datetime column, but I want to change the type of column, not just to show. I have google it but I do not get the right answer.

Comment: You can't change the definition of `DateTime`.  You can either just select `Year(VitiBotimit)` or change the column to `Int` and only store the year.

Comment: There is no particular datatype to store year in sql server, INT is the right one.

Comment: Int is the correct one if you want to make a column to hold only the year.  But why strip data out of your data when you can just query for it?

Comment: You ether store valid dates in `DATE` field or your create INT column to store integer values. If you need to store date but only want to display year than you can use `YEAR(column_name)` or `DATEPART(YEAR, column_name)`

Comment: I would recommend not storing year information in an int column. It is still relevant date information and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
SELECT YEAR(VitiBotimit)
FROM dbo.borrowing
```

`DATETIME` in SQL Server *has* no format - it's an 8-byte binary value - and therefore you cannot *change* the format.

You only get a *format* (of your choice) when you select the value from the table. If you only need the year - select it that way.

Comment: Thank you all, I will use select query.